# Detecting digital clipping in audio signal

Tags: python, audio, python-2.7, audio-recording

Given an audio byte array *data* in python like so

```
inp = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE, alsaaudio.PCM_NONBLOCK, card)

# Set attributes: Mono, 48000 Hz, 16 bit little endian samples
inp.setchannels(1)
inp.setrate(48000)
inp.setformat(alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)
l, data = inp.read()
```

How do I detect digital clipping, which value does *data* have to exceed to be sure that it was digitally clipped?

Comment: What do you mean by overdrive?  Digital clipping?  Data has to equal the maximum or minimum values for a 16-bit signed integer, for more than two or three samples, for there to be clipping.

Comment: When you listen to overdriven audio, it is distorted in cases when people touch a microphone or the circuit is short-circuited somewhere or they shout too loud. I presume this is being called digital clipping then.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So basically between −32.768 and 32.767? So if I use if audioop.max(data,2) >= 32767 || if audioop.max(data,2) <= -32767 I should be having clipping?

Comment: Overdriven audio can occur anywhere in the audio signal chain.  Sometimes it is deliberate, especially in electric guitar amps.  Digital clipping is different; it occurs when there are no more bits left to represent the amplitude of the signal.

Comment: Yes, basically that.  If you see three or more successive samples at -32768, or three or more successive samples at 32767, clipping has probably occurred.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I updated the comment. Great that's something I can work with. Write an answer like that if you want it accepted by me.

Comment: You don't usually want to use `>= 32767`. Digital clipping means it will be _exactly_ 32767 (or -32768). If it's _greater_, that means you don't have the data you think you have (e.g., wrong format, or maybe you're naively adding two signals and causing the problem in the first place). So, if you ever want to handle both `>` and `==`, you want to handle them completely differently.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but here is an API I built that will detect clipping for you: https://www.tinydrop.io/documentation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overdrive is basically gain distortion. It raises the voltage to the point that the driver just cuts the top off and thus distorts the signal. If you need to test this in a digital sense, it would be hard clipping. So you would need to search for values that pass the maximum threshold. With 16-bit audio files the clip is going to be 0db by the nature of it. Because if theres no more bits left to save to, then the software will automatically chop it off to the maximum a 16 bit integer can hold. Unfortunately if the track had been previously distorted and then had the volume lowered so as to blend into the mix better, your probably not going to find it. Unless that is, what you're examining is the only sound source on the track, it which case just find the maximum for the track and set that as your threshold. I can say though that hard clipping shows up as a square wave, so you could search for consecutively identical values for a time period longer then a common audible wave (as to ignore legitimate square wave tones). Thats about the best I can do for you though.